# spring boot json map

Tags: json, spring-boot

How to map json?
I am using Spring Boot.
I can't do it for a few days. Help.

```
  {
      "type": "1C",
      "counterparty": {
          "name": "BBB",
          "inn": "123456789",
          "kpp": ""
      },
      "nomenclatures": [
          {
              "cod": [{"type":"1C", "val":"YU-1234"}],
              "name": "MMM",
              "article": "123"
          }
      ]
  }
```

Comment: Spring Boot uses the Jackson JSON library.  I would recommend using that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some mapper library for doing it easily. `Jackson` library is one of them and it comes with springboot web by defaut.

**Using Jackson Library**

`TargetObject` is a POJO on which json is going to be mapped.

```
String in = "{\"type\":\"1C\",\"counterparty\":{\"name\":\"BBB\",\"inn\":\"123456789\",\"kpp\":\"\"},\"nomenclatures\":[{\"cod\":[{\"type\":\"1C\",\"val\":\"YU-1234\"}],\"name\":\"MMM\",\"article\":\"123\"}]}";

TargetObject targetObject = (TargetObject) convertStringToObject(in, TargetObject.class);
// Print the object details
```

You can invoke the following method.

```
  public static Object convertStringToObject(String jsonString, Class<?> objectType) {
    Object mappedObject = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
      mappedObject = mapper.readValue(jsonString, objectType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO: Handle exception here
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mappedObject;
  }
```

For the  sake of brevity, I didn't use the setter/getter so you should properly use encapsulation.

```
public class TargetObject {

  public String type;
  public Counterparty counterparty;
  public ArrayList<Nomenclature> nomenclatures;

  public static class Cod {
    public String type;
    public String val;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      builder.append("Cod [type=").append(type).append(", val=").append(val).append("]");
      return builder.toString();
    }

  }

  public static class Counterparty {
    public String name;
    public String inn;
    public String kpp;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      builder.append("Counterparty [name=").append(name).append(", inn=").append(inn)
          .append(", kpp=").append(kpp).append("]");
      return builder.toString();
    }

  }

  public static class Nomenclature {
    public ArrayList<Cod> cod;
    public String name;
    public String article;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      builder.append("Nomenclature [cod=").append(cod).append(", name=").append(name)
          .append(", article=").append(article).append("]");
      return builder.toString();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("TargetObject [type=").append(type).append(", counterparty=")
        .append(counterparty).append(", nomenclatures=").append(nomenclatures).append("]");
    return builder.toString();
  }

}
```

**OR**

You can do the same by using google `gson` library. If you're using maven you can add the dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Following is the driver code where json string mapped to java object with the help of gson library.

```
String in = "{\"type\":\"1C\",\"counterparty\":{\"name\":\"BBB\",\"inn\":\"123456789\",\"kpp\":\"\"},\"nomenclatures\":[{\"cod\":[{\"type\":\"1C\",\"val\":\"YU-1234\"}],\"name\":\"MMM\",\"article\":\"123\"}]}";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
TargetObject targetObject = gson.fromJson(in, TargetObject.class);
// You can print here the object.
```